# Will the water column group falling from the shower get thinner and thinner?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

We all know that the water column falling from the faucet will become thinner and thinner,

[image]

so will the diameter (phi) of the water column group falling from the shower become thinner and thinner?
Assuming that the diameter of each hole in the shower is the same, the holes are dense and the axes of the holes are parallel to each other.

[image: φ]

My answer is yes, because the water column falling from each hole will become thinner and thinner, so the gap between the water column will become larger and larger. In this way, the air pressure in the gap will be lower and lower, and under the action of atmospheric pressure, Phi will be thinner and thinner.

Comment: Have you not conducted the experiment yourself? See this [image](https://www.bobvila.com/articles/no-hot-water/) for example. It doesn't seem like the different streams converge.

Comment: @Deep I can't see your picture.